# How to save Azure AD B2C users to Cosmos DB when they sign up?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-ad-b2c

When a user signs up to an Azure AD B2C tenant on my single page application, I want to atomically save a JSON data like `{userId: "userId", email: "emailAddress}` to a Cosmos DB container. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an API connector at sign up. This will call your API right before the account is created into AAD B2C (or at any point in custom policy). AAD B2C can send all data/claims to any endpoint you specify.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Your API should then call Cosmos DB API to create the record.

Comment: I am looking for a similar solution but I am unsure how to do it using an api connector:
If I understand it correctly, there are three different triggers for connectors:
1. After signing in with identity provider
2. Before creating the user
3. Before sending the token (preview)

But all of them seem wrong for the scenario. The first one does not apply to local accounts, the second one runs before the actual creation and the third one for each token generation. Is there any way to run a connector/script AFTER the user creation?

Comment: Use custom policy. https://aka.ms/ief